# Microsoft Graph API to get outlook calendar events not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are working on a web part for SharePoint Online where logged in user is able to see their outlook events. We are using Microsoft Graph API to fetch event from  outlook as https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$top=1000.

It is working good. But it is not showing a particular occurrence if that occurrence is modified. For example, I have created an event that will occurs every Friday and I change a single occurrence to Saturday, then this particular occurrence does not returned by Graph API.

Also we tried on Graph Explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and here also it is missing.

Please help what might be the issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh,

Have you tried using a Delta request?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0

This will provide you with changes to existing events.